# Knockout observable array remove after index

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm looking for a way in knockout to remove all the elements in an observable array which come after a given index.

A for-loop to do that is inefficient since removing one element at a time triggers change notifications with every removal. Is there anything out of the box ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (note that HowMany is optional and if you don't specify it, all the items after StartIndex will be removed):

```
myObservableArray.splice(StartIndex, HowMany)
```

If you need to remove items that have certain properties, you can pass a function returning a boolean value to knockout's remove function, for example:

```
myObservableArray.remove(function(item) { return item.property > YourValue })
```

+
Quote from knockout docs: [LINK](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html)

```
Normally, an observableArray notifies its subscribers immediately, as soon as it’s 
changed. But if an observableArray is changed repeatedly or triggers expensive updates,
you may get better performance by limiting or delaying change notifications. This is
accomplished using the rateLimit extender like this:

// Ensure it notifies about changes no more than once per 50-millisecond period
myViewModel.myObservableArray.extend({ rateLimit: 50 });
```

Comment: item.id is undefined in my case, I don't keep indexes in my models. Great info about change notification ! Need to remember that.

Comment: So maybe just using array.splice(indexOfStart,HowMany)?

Comment: Oh, apparently Knockout provides splice on observable arrays ! I will use that. Feel free to update your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: It's already updated. apparently You didn't refresh the page ;)